# SQL Query on Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a Database (fields) with rows: `ID, field_name, field_label.`
I want to build an array with all the avail records.

fields_model is :

```
public function getFields() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('fields');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {
        die("Error");
    }

    $fields = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $fields[$row->id]['nume'] = $row->field_name;
        $fields[$row->id]['label'] = $row->field_label;
    }
    // Pass the result back to the controller
    return $fields;


}
```

In controller i have:

```
    $this->load->model('fields_model');
    $data['fields'] = $this->fields_model->getFields();
```

But i receive : `Message: Array to string conversion error` 
Any ideea?. Thanks

Comment: May I ask, on which line are you getting the error?

Comment: Basically this error "Message: Array to string conversion error" means you are trying to echo a string, however array is given. Try to use print_r($your_array_variable) to understand better.

Answer (score 1):

**In model**

```
    function getFields()
    {

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * from fields");
        $result = $query->result_array();
        return $result;
    }
```

**In Controller**

```
    $this->load->model('fields_model');
    $data['fields'] = $this->fields_model->getFields();

    if (empty($data['fields']))
    {
        echo "Empty data";
    }
    else
    {
        return $result;
    }
```

**In view**

```
<?php
    foreach ( $fields as $new_item )
    {
        echo $new_item['nume'];
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $new_item['label'];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code-

```
 public function getFields() {
    $this->db->select('*')->from('fields');

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if (!$query->num_rows() > 0) {
        die("Error");
    }

    $fields = array();

    foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
        $fields[$row->id]['nume'] = $row->field_name;
        $fields[$row->id]['label'] = $row->field_label;
        $fields_array[]=$fields;
    }
    // Pass the result back to the controller
    return $fields_array;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line

```
$fields = array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
public function getFields() {
    $query = $this->db->get('fields');
    $result = $query->result();

    $array = array();
    foreach($result as $field){
        $element = array(
            'nume' => $field->field_name,
            'label'=> $field->field_label
        );
        array_push($array, $element);
    }

    return $array;
}
```